# Why does this Verilog testbench not undergo a race condition?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, testbench, race-condition

This is the testbench in question:

```
module tb;
    reg a,b;

    initial begin
        $display("a=%0d | b=%0d", a,b);

        a = 1;
        b = 0;
        a <= b;
        b <= a;
    end
endmodule
```

Ignoring the evaluation of RHS of non-blocking assignments, which will be assigned to the LHS in the NBA region, the active region consists of:

- `$display`
- `a=1`
- `b=0`

Since the active region is non-deterministic in nature, $display will can now either print the default values of a and b, ie. `x x`, or their values after the assignment, ie. `1 0`, or their values after the assignment of any one of the variable, ie. `1 x` or `x 0`, ultimately resulting in a race condition.

This is how I think it should work internally. But I was told by my teacher that this does not undergo any race condition. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of execution of statements *within a single* `begin/end` process is always deterministic. So the `$display` statement prints `x` as the values for `a` and `b`. Race conditions are *between multiple processes* (created by multiple `initial` or `always` constructs) executing in the same active region.

Comment: Can you also explain how things change if I replace `$display` with `#0 $display`? Will this push the `$display` command in the inactive region?

Comment: It won't change a thing for this example--there is still only one process. Also, nothing executes in the inactive region. The `#0` suspends the process to the inactive region waiting for the active region to finish (there is nothing else in active region in this example when encountering the #0.) So the process resumes immediately executing the next statement, which is the $display.

Comment: Okay, got it. Two more cases: 1. If I replace `begin...end` with `fork...join` in the orginal code and 2. if I then replace `$display` with `#0 $display` in case 1. In case 1, it will create a race condition whereas in case 2, the race will be avoided and output will be `a=1 | b=0`. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. BTW, [so] suggests you edit your question or ask new questions rather than discussions in comments